# Best approach for passing passwords to command line applications

Tags: automation, passwords, design-patterns

What do you thing it will be the optimal method of passing passwords to different applications.

Giving the password as a command line argument is not acceptable because this will be visible in logs - especially in an **automation system**.

At this moment I'm considering two possibilities: providing the password in a file or temporary setting it in an environment variable.

Please give your recommendation and explain it.

Comment: what is the *reason* you need to pass a password to another program?

Comment: I'm undecided as to whether this belongs here on in serverfault.

Comment: Reasons: source control login, or login to other services.